# 5v output to 3.3v?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, raspberry-pi, input, output

I have a microcontroller and a Raspberry Pi, both running off of the same 5v supply, in parallel. The microcontroller has 4 5v output pins and the other is a Raspberry Pi, that can only accept inputs of 3.3v and less.

Obviously I cannot directly connect the outputs to the inputs - that'll fry the Raspberry Pi.

How can I connect 5v outputs to the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a level translator such as the one sold by [sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10403).

Hook one VCC to 5V and the other to 3.3V on the Rasberry Pi.

Comment: With a little more research, I found [this](http://adafruit.com/products/757). This appears to be exactly what I need, thank you.

Comment: For a single-directional connection like OP seems to be asking about, a voltage divider will be cheaper than a translator chip.

Comment: @ThePhoton: True.

Comment: That's what I thought I could do at first, but in this case buying the resistors for the dividers + shipping will end up costing the same as this chip, which will take up less space than veroboard.

Answer (score 2):

If the connection is going one way: from 5V to 3.3V, then in addition to a dedicated chip, a variety of voltage shifting techniques are available, as described in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43498/how-can-i-use-a-12-v-input-on-a-digital-arduino-pin/60436#60436) post.  The most relevant (cheapest, easiest, etc) are:

- Voltage divider (two resistors connected in series from your +5 output to GND with the center "tap" connected to your 3.3V input
- Diode voltage down shifter circuit (diode connected in series with a resistor to the lower voltage, 3.3V in this case)