# Investigate methods for analog Input Overvoltage fault protection

Tags: adc, analog, automotive, protection, zener

I have 8 analog input coming from various 5v and 3.3v sensors that have to be interfaced to a 3.3v micro-controller. The main system voltage is 24v-48v , i need to protect the ADC inputs against over-voltage from misuse , not ESD events. So if by mistake the 48v is connected instead of the sensor.

after looking into the following threads :

[How would I design a protection clipper circuit for ADC input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/how-would-i-design-a-protection-clipper-circuit-for-adc-input)

[ADC over-voltage input protection while keeping accuracy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170176/adc-over-voltage-input-protection-while-keeping-accuracy)

i tried the following :

- **Approach 1: Resistor and Zener**

This approach is fine on digital pins but confirmed what people said in the posts about voltage drop and ADC error. I heard that using a shunt regulator like the TL431 instead could help but haven't tried it!?

- **Approach 2: Series Resistor and External clipping diodes**

The approach works fine it have tries BAS70,BAT54 and similar , in order to get lower drop i have found that using power (1A) schottky is better because they have much lower voltage drop at 1-25mA .

- **Approach 3: OPAMP, Resistor and diode**

this approach i have found is not very common , and work fairly well , similar to approach 2 but more complicated.

[image: Circuit]

- **Approach 4: Unity Gain opamp with internal Clamp**

Texas instruments have a product for this role exclusively.
[OP698](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiovYq4yO3NAhUE5xoKHe55CucQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Fproduct%2FOPA698&usg=AFQjCNFd7tRpneAj55aDBDDILVX1TmB9Ng)

**BUT:** this lowest single supply is 5v not 3.3v , and the maximum clamping voltage is lower than the rail . and it does not tell how much is the maximum input voltage. and it takes PCB space , 4 resistors and 1 SO-08 IC per input.

**Question :**

At this point of search i got a bit frustrated and i think now that **Approach 2** is the best in terms of robustness and space, please help and state any other approach i am missing ??
I am also interested in exotic solutions similar to automotive Input/ Output ICs that have multiple inputs and protection built in to interface the processors to harsh environment. similar to this [MAX6816](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwio14OZze3NAhVCbBoKHU6-AtsQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.maximintegrated.com%2Fen%2Fdatasheet%2Findex.mvp%2Fid%2F1896&usg=AFQjCNHFS5wIOe4tPUnrONHFeC3Hjx7OYg) used for digital signals.

Comment: I would use a combination of 1 and 2. Approach 2 relies on the 3.3 V supply staying 3.3 V, if you inject a lot of current it might become higher than 3.3 V, possibly damaging the microC as well. So I would use the diodes to clamp to ground and a Vcc which has a zener diode to prevent it from becoming too high. A 3.6 V zener on the 3.3 V supply might do the job. The TL431 is just a fancy zener diode, you don't need it here.

Comment: @FakeMoustache , sounds good , do you agree that using power schotkky diodes like CDBM1100 is better than small signal ones like BAT54?? (to get lower voltage drop at 1-25mA) ,, and does the mentioned zener on power supply have to be beefy , or just a normal zener since the resistor is series with clamping diodes will limit its power dissipation ??

Comment: I don't think you need Schottky diodes, as long as the current is limited then a one diode drop will be OK. A normal 400 mW zener should be enough as again the current must be limited by a series resistor. The resistor has to do most of the work so to say.

Comment: Power schottky diodes have high capacitance, which may lower the bandwidth of your input.
They also have high reverse leakage currents, which will introduce a temperature-dependent DC-bias in your analog input.
So no, power schottkys are generally not a good idea for clamping analog inputs.